# Animated view gets dismissed when textfield is active?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield, swift2, uiviewanimation

I have a UIViewController which has UITableView and on to the UITableView I am animating a UIView when the button is selected in the tableview cell. In the UIView I have a UITextField, now when I click in the textfield the UIView disappears.

I am doing this in Swift 2.0. Any suggestions about this issue and if possible with some explanation/sample code reference.

Below is the animation process I am doing when the button is selected in UITableViewCell

```
if !cell.btnBuy.selected
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.buyView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.buyView.frame.origin.y - (56.0 + 64.0 + 43.0 + self.SearchBar.frame.origin.y + self.Segment.frame.origin.y), self.view.frame.size.width, 412.0)
            }) { (finished) -> Void in}
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }
```

[image: View after selecting button in tableview cell]
[image: View after clicking on the textfield]

Thanks.

Comment: have to tried to animate it in GraphicService Thread using dispatch_async.

Comment: @AnkitThakur nope can you suggest how to do that, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.buyView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.buyView.frame.origin.y - (56.0 + 64.0 + 43.0 + self.SearchBar.frame.origin.y + self.Segment.frame.origin.y), self.view.frame.size.width, 412.0)
            }) { (finished) -> Void in}
        UIView.commitAnimations()
});
```

Comment: @ AnkitThakur still I see the UIView is getting disappeared when clicked on the textfield.